# Temperature with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Do iOS devices have a termometer, to find out the current temperature, anything, let it be even cpu temperature it doesn't matter, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get the temperature, but you don't care what temperature. i.e. You absolutely do not care what value is returned, and it will be completely meaningless because the CPU temp and outside temp don't relate in any way. So just use arc4random() and generate a random number, and use that.

Comment: Or you can connect to some online weather site like Yahoo! And download the temperature for the current location.

Comment: Or you can buy one here: http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/reviews/entry/idevices-igrill-bluetooth-cooking-thermometer-for-ios-devices/ :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it's not accessible from Public API's

Comment: It, means that i have no acces to to it ??

Comment: @Florik. Yes, that is what it means.